# Disable node-inspector Chrome console errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, node-inspector

Node-inspector is working fine with regard to debugging successfully. However, there are multiple errors that pop up in the console such as

```
Runtime.getProperties failed.
Error: No scopes
```

This is apparently fixed by downgrading to a different NodeJS version, which I cannot do for various reasons. I really don't mind the errors, except for the fact that every time one pops up, the Chrome debugger moves from the "Sources" view to the "Console" view, which is very distracting when it happens every single time I have to step through the code.

Any clues on how to disable these errors, or otherwise stop the window from moving to the console window, or otherwise stop the errors all together?

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in Node Inspecto 0.11.0